# Sendhub api issue

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am using sendhub API.

https://www.sendhub.com/developer/

and getting this error.

The format indicated 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' had no available deserialization method. Please check your `formats` and `content_types` on your Serializer.

The code I am using is:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type: application/json");
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

                if(LOCAL_MODE){
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, FALSE);
                 }

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

                $data = '{
                   "contacts": [
                      1111
                   ],
                   "text": "Testing"
                }';

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
                echo $result=curl_exec ($ch);
                echo curl_error($ch);
```

Can anybody help me how to solve this issue.

Thank You.

Comment: hey sheeraz can you help me to give me full code with url and how to add key and user name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Content-Type is not being sent correctly.

The message "The format indicated 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' had no available deserialization method." indicates the server is reading the content type as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' rather than 'application/json'.

You should be setting the content type like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

(note the CURLOPT_HEADER is now CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER)

Assuming that your url (including the username and apikey) are correct and the contact ids supplied exist this should now work.

Comment: As a follow up, I'd recommend that you use curl with the -vv argument to test your REST requests so you can be sure what's going out over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

```
// The code
$vs_user = $t_user->getAppConfig()->get('sms_user');
$vs_api_key = $t_user->getAppConfig()->get('sms_api_key');
$vs_url = "https://api.sendhub.com/v1/messages/?username={$vs_user}&api_key={$vs_api_key}";
$o_ch = curl_init();
$ps_message = stripslashes(rawurldecode($ps_message));
$ps_message = trim(preg_replace("!\n+!","\\"."n", $ps_message));
curl_setopt($o_ch, CURLOPT_URL, $vs_url);
curl_setopt($o_ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($o_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($o_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"contacts":['.$vn_sendhub_contact_id.'],"text":"'.$ps_message.'"}');
curl_setopt($o_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$vs_return = curl_exec($o_ch);
$va_return = json_decode($vs_return);
curl_close($o_ch);
```

Check mine php which i use